# Replacing .createDocument() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to replace document.createElement in jQuery, is there any way to do so?

```
for (let word in myDictionary) {
    let buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
    $(buttonElement).html(word);
    $(buttonElement).on("click", createOnClickListener(myDictionary[word]));

    let listItemElement = document.createElement("li");
    $(listItemElement).append(buttonElement);
    $(buttonListElement).append(listItemElement);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('<tagname>')` creates an element wrapped in jQuery object

```
let $button = $('<button>').html(word).on('click', createOnClickListener(myDictionary[word]));
let $listItem = $('<li>').append($button);
```